# init.d script wont run execute command but command works when manully ran in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, command, init.d

I have the following command that my init.d unicorn script runs.
This commands works with no issue manually in terminal but refuses to
work in my init.d/unicorn file

```
cd /var/www/myapp/current && ( RAILS_ENV=production BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/var/www/myapp/current/Gemfile /usr/bin/env bundle exec unicorn -c /var/www/myapp/current/config/unicorn/production.rb -E deployment -D )
```

Here is the init.d file

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: unicorn
# Required-Start: postgresql nginx
# Required-Stop: 
# Should-Start: 
# Should-Stop: 
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop unicorn
# Description: UNICORN
### END INIT INFO
set -e
APP_ROOT=/var/www/myapp/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
RAILS_ENV=production
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$APP_ROOT/Gemfile
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT && ( RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$APP_ROOT/Gemfile /usr/bin/env bundle exec unicorn -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn/$RAILS_ENV.rb -E deployment -D )"

action="$1"
set -u

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
        test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

case $action in
start)
        sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
        $CMD
        ;;
stop)
        sig QUIT && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: What does "refuses to work" mean exactly?

Comment: You are putting your commands in `CMD` but then you never use it. You should probably not be using a variable here anyhow; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1):

Abstracting the CMD variable to a function fixed the issue.
As indirectly suggested by tripleee's resource shared.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: unicorn
# Required-Start: postgresql nginx
# Required-Stop:
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop unicorn
# Description: UNICORN
### END INIT INFO
set -e
APP_ROOT=/var/www/myapp/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
RAILS_ENV=production
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$APP_ROOT/Gemfile
action="$1"
set -u

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

run(){
        cd $APP_ROOT && ( RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$APP_ROOT/Gemfile /usr/bin/env bundle exec unicorn -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn/$RAILS_ENV.rb -E deployment -D )
}

sig () {
        test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

case $action in
start)
        sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
        run
        ;;
stop)
        sig QUIT && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: I don't see why you would want or need to run `env` in a subshell. You can probably remove the parentheses after the `cd`.